# Proper way to build data structure for mySQL/PHP app that deals with a variable amount of quality specifications

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hello and thanks for taking the time to help me with my small conundrum.

I'm trying to discern the best way to lay out the necessary tables and fields, as well as the best method of displaying/updating this information.

I'm building a web app that deals in part with inventory levels across customer accounts. Customer can have a variety of products they hold in inventory, which also contain a set of quality specifications. While I presently have a short list of products that a customer may hold in inventory, that list will almost certainly grow. The list of quality specifications among these products will also certainly grow. Some quality specifications are shared between *all* products, such as "weight". Others are unique to a specific product. Most are measured in a numerical value, however some are simply strings of text (however depending on the product, that text is a set value string.) These items would finally contain a price per unit, and whether or not they were for sale at that time.

So far we know we have:

**List of products** - Each product will have a unique description among other small properties.
**Quantity of said product** - Measured in metric tonnes.
**Quality Specifications** - Some shared between all products, others unique to a single product.
**Product Price** - and whether they are presently for sale or not.

My intended execution:

**Table of customers** - Pretty standard stuff, who they are bla bla
**Table of product types** - containing the descriptions as well as weight conversions properties.
**Table of quality specifications** -  This table would contain all of the possible quality specifications.
**Table of inventory** - containing quantity of product as well as desired pricing, and if they are for sale or not.

My intention was to JOIN the quality specification table to the inventory table, then JOIN the inventory table to both the customers and product types tables. To display the quality specifications, a FOREACH loop with key=>value pairs to display the name of the quality specification (field name) and it's value. Any field that was NULL, the loop could ignore, thereby removing quality specifications from products that don't need them.

I know this isn't the best approach. I'll need to be able to update the quality specifications to each item as they change on a per-customer-inventory basis, as well as introduce new products and perhaps new quality specifications down the line, ideally through the app, however it's something that isn't so frequent that it would be a problem to simply update the tables manually. I'm guessing it would happen a few times a year, if even.

I could most certainly use any help or insight anyone with a bit more experience might be able to provide. I just feel like I'm not seeing this in the right way of doing it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Most inventory systems have a basic item called a SKU -- stock keeping unit.  A SKU might be a 500g can of Spam, or a kilogram of medium-quality butter.  Then, you can describe how many units of each SKU each customer possesses. It's not clear how to get from your product-type and quality tables to a list of SKUs.

Comment: Hey thanks! Each item is stored in Metric tonne,so it shouldn't be a problem, correct?

Comment: If you're measuring in tonnes, you probably want customers to be able to possess fractions of a tonne.  E.g. Joe has half a tonne of medium-weight sand, and John has two tonnes of pea gravel, etc.  It's possible you're making things too complicated by splitting out quality and product type into separate tables. You're likely to have an easier time if you have a table with one row for each type / grade of product.  (It would make no sense for Joe to have half a can of Spam, of course.)

Comment: While this is certainly possible, almost all of the time the inventory levels will be well over a single tonne. I do appreciate that observation, as it is entirely possible a new product could be introduced in the future that has much smaller units. With regards to merging the Product table and the Quality table, the problem I see for that is that each product does contain some specific information about it as well, such as conversion units into other measurement units, etc... Any other holes you see in the approach so far? I do very much appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

What a large project you are undertaking.  I hope you enjoy it.

There is no simple answer to your question but I will refer you to my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376535/mysql-organizing-database-content-sports-league/18377917#18377917) which had very similar requirements and covers the basics of database normalisation.  If you look up 4th Normal form on google, you'll get a lot more advanced info too.

You are both very close to having a good system in mind (because you have actually designed it first which is awesome) and far off because you have underestimated the amount of tables and the complexity involved.

I have looked into something similar myself for managing stock in a medical centre and found a large number of inexpensive web apps that were not really suited to my needs but sound like they might suit yours.  You could spend a lot of time writing an app that has already been done better - from a commercial point of view, it rarely makes sense to write your own app for your own purposes when you can buy one off the shelf.  Fun though.

Even if you decide to write your own, there is absolutely nothing wrong with looking at someone else's and seeing if you can't improve it.

BTW:  I'd not leave the back end data manipulation features till last.  They are boring but essential and need to be coded before you do the fun stuff, otherwise you'll probably end up in a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your input and references. This is a project I'll be expanding on greatly over the next year or so, so I've decided to build it from the ground up to be as form fitting as I'd like. There are a lot of further components that will come in to interact with these components as well. While I am familiar with 4th normal, I do ask how important it would be to strictly adhere to it with regards to the greater challenges a largely fragmented table structure would create when interacting with the data? I'm not ignoring it, but for instance a large... (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) large QUALITY table with fields for each possible quality value, whereby a loop would ignore NULL values in the output could accomplish the needs without as many tables to a pretty decent degree, no?